# How do I set a $routeProvider to redirect the page when there is a parameter in the url?

Tags: angularjs, angular-routing

I have a link on my page that has an id parameter (123) as listed below:

```
ng-click="setRoute('user/123/view')"
```

I am unable to get the `$routeProvider` below to work:

```
$routeProvider.when('/user/:id/view', {
    templateUrl: 'partials/user/nav.html',
    controller: 'UserCtrl'
});
```

What am I missing? I have gotten similar code to work, but when I don't have a parameter. What is it about the parameter that I am doing incorrectly?

Comment: No errors in the console? does the template load does a debug point hit in your UserCtrl

Comment: What does the link look like?

Comment: The link is triggered by ``ng-click``.

Comment: what does setRoute() do? This is not an angular function, so the error might be there.

Comment: This is what I have for setRoute(). The scope of the controller is in the body tag: function MainCtrl($scope,$location){
    $scope.setRoute = function(route){
        $location.path(route);
    };
}

Comment: The code you have provided works when I plug it in to a small Angular app (check it out at http://plnkr.co/edit/ELnU6HVm4egYGWQHGtgj), so the error is most likely elsewhere. What is actually happening when the error occurs? Is the page rendering but then you can't access the id parameter? Or are you being routed to a blank page?